# Changing directory in google colab

Tags: python, directory

I am using Google Colab to practice some coding and trying to import files from Excel. I tried to change the directory to my one drive folder or driver D, but it doesn't work. Python is the name of the folder that contains my Excel file.

Here is the code I used:os.chdir(r"D:/Python")

Here is the error I take: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/Python'

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729963/)

There an answer for creating temporary URLs

Another answer for using [onedrivesdk](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/blob/master/README.md#onedrive)